# How do I get vectors orthogonal to the one generated by the spherical coordinate formula?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, spherical-coordinates

Given $\theta \in [0,\pi)$, $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$, and $F$:

$F : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3,\;
F(\theta, \phi) = \left[\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta),\ \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta),\ \cos(\theta) \right]$,

What are the formulas:

$G, H: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 \\
 G(\theta, \phi) = ? \\
 H(\theta, \phi) = ?$,

such that

$F(\theta, \phi) \perp G(\theta, \phi) \perp H(\theta, \phi) \quad \forall \ \theta \in [0,\pi), \, \phi \in [0,2\pi).$

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Could you explain what is the little symbol that is a square with a $>$ in it?

Comment: I'm sorry, what square? Are you seeing [the same as me](http://i.imgur.com/aJdEHkB.png)? I've took the variable names from Wikipedia's article on spherical coordinates. `⟂` means orthogonal. `∈` is member of.

Comment: I see. The orthogonal sign does not look right here. But I can see it correctly in your link. Here you can learn how to type MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. That will make it look much nicer.

Comment: I love how this question was edited to the point of being too smart for myself to understand!

Comment: @MaiaVictor I'm not sure what you mean. I simply transcribed what you had in ASCII into  LaTeX. I looks like the only thing I changed was moving the definitions of $\theta$ and $\phi$ to the top and using $\forall$ instead of the words "for any". If I accidentally messed up something, please edit it to be correct.

Comment: It was just a joke, it is fine. It is just that it is so pretty it doesn't look like something I'd write. I'm not a LaTeX guy (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a sphere, its tangential vectors satisfy the orthogonality. So we find

$$F_{\theta}=\frac{dF}{d\theta}=(\cos \phi\cos\theta, \sin\phi\cos\theta, -\sin\theta), F_{\phi}=\frac{dF}{d\phi}=(-\sin\phi\sin\theta, \cos\phi\sin\theta, 0)$$

You can see $F_{\theta}$ satisfies the conditions for $G$. But $F_{\phi}$ is not $(0,1,0)$ at $(0,0)$. To get the second component to equal $1$ when $\theta=0$ and $\phi=0$, we change the second component of $F_{\phi}$ to $\cos\phi\cos\theta$. Now to maintain orthogonality, which means dot product equals zero, we have to change the first component to $-\sin\phi\cos\theta$. This gives 
$$H=(-\sin\phi\cos\theta,\cos\phi\cos\theta,0)$$